# Isekai manga where the main character gets summoned and brings the goddess with him

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

This is a manga where the main character has S luck and is summoned to a different world, but instead brings the goddess with him. With his luck, he spins a raffle drum and wins things such as a legendary sword to a lake house. With that, eventually the goddess somewhat falls for the main character.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is "S luck"?  When and where did you read this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this manga mostly in black & white or full colour?

Comment: Which goddess is "_the_ goddess?"

Answer (score 8):

This is *[I Rose Suddenly in The Alternate World By Overwhelming Gacha With Luck!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/attouteki-gacha-un-de-isekai-wo-nariagaru)*

> It was a gacha experience in a world of swords and magic that the late Jinta Kazama reincarnated in after an accident. But after the reincarnation, a status abnormality was found. **His [Luck] stat had a numerical value of [999,999], when its normal maximum was [99]**, he has become—– **The Strongest weapon of mythlogical grade was won in the first gacha! “I won this house with gacha!”**

The synopsis is a solid match for the question. After dying, he reincarnates in another world and brings the goddess in charge of his reincarnation along with him.

Answer (score 2):

The wording of your question is a little confusing, but it sounds like it could match [KonoSuba: God's Blessing on this Wonderful World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KonoSuba). In particular (taken from the linked WP article and some related articles, plus the [fan wiki](https://konosuba.fandom.com/wiki/Kono_Subarashii_Sekai_ni_Shukufuku_wo!_Wiki)):

> Following an untimely and embarrassing death, Kazuma Satō, a Japanese teenage shut-in NEET, meets a goddess named Aqua, who offers to reincarnate him in a parallel world with MMORPG elements, where he can go on adventures and battle monsters. Despite being offered a superpowered item or ability to use in this new world, Kazuma, following some provocation, chooses Aqua herself to accompany him to the town of Axel, quickly finding her absent-mindedness to be less than beneficial.
>
> He has average stats in crucial categories, but above average intelligence and extremely high luck, neither of which are important for adventurers.

(About their mansion)

> The mansion used to have a ghost problem because Aqua created a barrier around a nearby graveyard, causing the spirits of the graveyard to move to the mansion. Kazuma and his party were allowed to stay in the mansion for the winter after exorcising it, but the owner told them they could live there after there were no more rumors about it being haunted

I admit that winning a sword and a lake house in a lottery don't seem to have a match, and while Aqua does occasionally admit to liking Kazuma it doesn't extend to love in the anime (or the manga, I think).